# svndumpfilter2 + Windows HowTo

Tags: svn, svndumpfilter

How do you get svndumpfilter2 or svndumpfilter3 working in Windows?

> type dump_file | svndumpfilter2 exclude xyz > filtered_dump_file

has no idea what svndumpfilter2 is regardless of where I put the script file.

Note:
Python is installed and I did add .py extension to the file => svndumpfilter2.py

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python on windows doesn't support pipes when called automatically.  You have to run python.exe on the .py file explicitly. e.g.:

```
type input.dump | C:\Python26\python.exe C:\Path\to\svndumpfilter3.py exclude xyz > output.dump
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have Python installed? If so, you should be able to get it to work by renaming the script to `svndumpfilter2.py` (or `svndumpfilter3.py`). Windows doesn't understand the shabang line at the top of the script

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
def foo():
```

Comment: Python is installed and I have added .py to files.